# Android - Problems using ProGuard and including Google maps Api

Tags: android, proguard, android-build

I am wondering if anyone can help me.

I am adding some maps functionality to an Android application. The build script uses
ProGuard.

Does anyone know how I can include the google maps api (maps.jar) in -libraryjars list without using an absolute path?

Part of the existing build script creates a new android project and it seems thats were the property android.jar (containing the location of that jar) is set. However, there does not seem to be a similar one to for maps.jar. Is there a way to set a similar property or some other way to get ProGuard to find the maps.jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

During a standard Android build, the Ant property `android.target.classpath` contains all required run-time libraries, including android.jar and maps.jar. This path is passed to the javac compiler (with -bootclasspath) and to ProGuard (with -libraryjars). This means that you shouldn't need to specify any additional -libraryjars yourself, on the condition that you have created or updated your Android project with the proper target (e.g. target id 23: "Android + Google APIs (API level 12)").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I did you respond earlier. The project has been shelved for the moment. I am still not completely familiar with the build script for the project. Once I am back working on it I will check that the android project is being created correctly and update the answer accordingly.